# Is jQuery UI Layout incompatible with jQuery 3.3.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[jQuery UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/index.cfm) works with older jquery but not newer jquery...

**Working example:**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://layout.jquery-dev.net/lib/js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://layout.jquery-dev.net//lib/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://layout.jquery-dev.net//lib/js/jquery.layout-1.2.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var myLayout;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        myLayout = $('body').layout({applyDefaultStyles: true });
     });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-layout-west">west</div>
<div class="ui-layout-center">center</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Not working example - newer jQuery**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
     integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://layout.jquery-dev.net//lib/js/jquery.layout-1.2.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var myLayout;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        myLayout = $('body').layout({applyDefaultStyles: true });
     });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-layout-west">west</div>
<div class="ui-layout-center">center</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this a breaking change in jQuery or is this a problem in jQuery UI Layout?

Comment: jQuery UI Layout Plug-in depend on jquery older version and in jquery new version they remove some property and method that's why its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery layout library uses `$.browser`, removed in jQuery 1.9, so it is only compatible with all the previous versions of jQuery and not the new ones.

Error:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

So this is a breaking change in jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

Go here and download the last version of 27/01/2018 uiLayout 1.6, this is working with jquery 3.2 just tested.
I also needed of a compatible versione for jquery 3 and this is perfect.
Bye

https://github.com/GedMarc/layout